# Does empty set entails everything?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, artificial-intelligence

I am new to propositional logic, and I am trying to figure out whether the below statement is correct:

```
[a |= c] or [ b |= c] → [a^b |= c]
```

First of all, it is obvious that

```
a^b ⊆ a and a^b ⊆ b.
```

Moreover, because either a |= c or b|= c are correct(or both), it seems that a^b must also entail c.
In other words:

M<sub>a ^ b</sub> ⊆  M<sub>a</sub>  . Also, when we say that  a |= c,

> we have M <sub>a</sub> ⊆ M<sub>c</sub>.

But what if the intersection of a and b is empty? Does this argument still hold?

Comment: " because either a |= c or b|= c are correct(or both), it seems that a^b must also entail c" Why does that seem to be the case?

Comment: Because M <sub>a ^ b</sub> ⊆  M <sub>a </sub> . Also, when we say that  a |= c, we have M <sub>a </sub>  ⊆ M <sub>c</sub> .

Comment: I don't understand your notation - use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Regardless, the point is that it's wrong: $a\cap b\models c$ need **not** be true even of $a\models c$ and $b\models c$, let alone if either $a\models c$ or $b\models c$. Maybe $a,b,c$ are *individual* sentences rather than sets of sentences and "^" is **conjunction** ("and"), $\wedge$, rather than intersection, $\cap$? In that case we do indeed have $a\wedge b\models c$ if either $a\models c$ or $b\models c$.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have edited my post and added those extra parts there.

Comment: Well, based on the problem description, a, b and c are sentences.

Comment: Then "^" cannot possibly be intersection, and statements like "a^b$\subseteq$a" are meaningless. I think "^" is supposed to be "$\wedge$" ("and").

Comment: You are mixing symbols for statements: $a \land b$ is the *conjunction* of statements $a$ and $b$ (reads: "$a$ and $b$") and symbols for sets: $M_{a \land b}$ is the set of models of statement $a \land b$ and in this case we have *intersection* and *inclusion*: $M_{a \land b} \subseteq M_a$.

Comment: The two are linked but different: $M_{a \land b}=M_a \cap M_b$

Comment: You said in a comment that $a,b,c$ are sentences, but in the question you talk about their intersection, and you write that some things are subsets of $a$ and $b$. Intersections and subsets make sense if you're talking about sets, but not if you're talking about sentences.

Answer (score 1):

$a\land b\vDash c$ means that there are *no* interpretations(aka models) which value $a\land b$ as true but $c$ as false.

If there are *no* interpretations which value $a\land b$ as true, then the above holds.  (See also **vacuous truths**)

The intersection of the models $\mathbf M_a$ and $\mathbf M_b$ being empty means there are no models which simultaneously value $a$ and $b$ as true.   Thus $\mathbf M_{a\land b}$ will be empty.   Therefore...